# How C++14 memory model works internally and how it compares to Bacon's Unified Theory of Garbage Collection

Tags: c++, multithreading, garbage-collection, c++14

Reading David Bacon's [Unified Theory of Garbage Collection](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/reading/bacon-garbage.pdf)
I found him mentioning that modern GCs are an hybrid of tracing and reference counting ones:

> Given the similarity in structure that we discovered between tracing
>   and reference counting, we began to re-examine various collector
>   architectures to understand the interplay between these styles of
>   collection. We observed that all realistic garbage collectors are in
>   fact some form of hybrid of tracing and reference counting. This
>   explains why an optimized “tracing collector” and an optimized
>   “reference counting collector” become more and more similar: because
>   they are in fact taking on characteristics of each other.

One of the things he mentions is the use of ZCT (Zero Count Table) to keep track of objects referenced from stack.
Another thing usually mentioned about ARC is:

1. It's not thread-safe as the increment is not atomic
2. If it's thread-safe it's slower than a GC

My questions:
How modern C++ (11/14/17) compare to this statements? Is this true that the ARC of C++ is hybrid and also use some elements of a tracing GC? I couldn't find anything on the web that points me to this, but the paper states very clearly that :

> We observed that all realistic garbage collectors are in
>   fact some form of hybrid of tracing and reference counting.

Is this true about modern C++? Or it's not considering a C++ ARC a "realistic garbage collector"?
Some people could argue that C++ has no GC, C++ has no tracing GC, but ARC is an approach to GC as it's stated on the paper:

> Tracing and reference counting are uniformly viewed as being
>   fundamentally different approaches to garbage collection that possess
>   very distinct performance properties. We have implemented
>   high performance collectors of both types, and in the process observed
>   that the more we optimized them, the more similarly they behaved —
>   that they seem to share some deep structure.

And is also presented on different other sources, like Wikipedia
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Reference_counting) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)

> Reference counting is a form of garbage collection whereby each object
>   has a count of the number of references to it. Garbage is identified
>   by having a reference count of zero. An object's reference count is
>   incremented when a reference to it is created, and decremented when a
>   reference is destroyed. When the count reaches zero, the object's
>   memory is reclaimed.

Also, there's any benchmark of modern C++ ARC against a GC allocation/deallocation (note: I'm not asking for a general comparison but a specific to memory management).

Last but not least, if I'm developing a single-thread application what's the advantage of having increment/decrement as atomic operations on C++? There's anyway to disable that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How modern C++ (11/14/17) compare to this statements?

There's no comparison. C++ never had, and does not have, any kind of automatic garbage collection of no longer referenced objects.

> Is this true about modern C++?

No, it's not true. C++ does not have garbage collection.

> Some people could argue that C++ has no GC,

There's no argument there. It's a fact. You will not find any kind of a description of any kind of a garbage collection implementation in the 1400+ pages of techical specifications that define the current C++ standard. It's not there. I looked.

> C++ has no tracing GC, but ARC is an approach to GC as it's stated
>   on the paper:

You are certainly free to come up with your own implementation of garbage collection, for your own classes, in C++. But that wouldn't make that a part of the language itself.

And, no, `std::shared_ptr`, et. al., is not garbage collection, even though it's reference counted. Hint: circular references.

> what's the advantage of having increment/decrement as atomic
>   operations on C++?

They, much less everything else in C++, has no inherit "advantage" of its own. This is like asking "what is the advance of having a car". For some people, owning a car makes their life easier. For others, it gives no benefit at all.

Similarly, atomic reference counting has advantages in ***specific*** use cases. For others it offers no advantages at all.

The correct question here would be "what are the advantages of having atomic increment/decrement versus [some alternative] in [a specific use case]".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting
In computer science, reference counting is a technique of storing the number of references, pointers, or handles to a resource such as an object, block of memory, disk space or other resource.

It may also refer, more specifically, to a garbage collection algorithm that uses these reference counts to deallocate objects which are no longer referenced.

Comment: Yes, it _may_ refer to garbage collection, which means it doesn't necessarily, which means there exist uses of RC which are not GC, which means the presence of RC is neither necessary nor sufficient to identify GC.

Comment: Herb Sutter, when describing a separate project, mentions that shared_ptr is garbage collection: 'Q: "Is this garbage collection?" A: Of course, and remember that so is reference counting (e.g., shared_ptr).'

https://github.com/hsutter/gcpp#q-is-this-garbage-collection

Answer (score 5):

You're taking a discussion of garbage collectors, finding an analogy between the properties described and bits of C++ behaviour, and then arguing that makes C++ a garbage-collected language.

That's not how it works. Those properties of GCs aren't proposed as a sufficient definition of a GC, such that anything exhibiting those properties must be a GC.

---

> > We observed that all realistic garbage collectors are in fact some form of hybrid of tracing and reference counting.
>
> Is this true about modern C++?

C++ *does not have a garbage collector* so this sentence is *not intended* to apply to it.

As you seem to suggest, we *could* work backwards, and say the C++ stack is its own ZCT in the sense described above, so provides a *very* limited form of tracing. It's not obvious that this is actually useful though, as it's essentially the degenerate case.

Similarly, RAII smart pointers *can* use reference counting, so we *can* argue that we have both tracing and ARC. Again, it isn't clear this is helpful.

> Also, there's any benchmark of modern C++ ARC against a GC allocation/deallocation (note: I'm not asking for a general comparison but a specific to memory management).

In general, it isn't a meaningful comparison.

C++ provides the ability to choose the right management scheme for every resource (including but not limited to memory), at a fine level of granularity, with complete control of layout, lifetime, initialization, cache effects etc. etc.

If you can be bothered to do all that, and do it well, you'll get better performance for programs where at least some of those things are relevant.

If you can't be bothered to do those things, or your program isn't really affected by them, you may get better performance from a general-purpose GC for less programming effort.

The only way to know is to benchmark, and you have to write the same program twice in different languages *and* be sure each implementation is well-optimized for the language facilities, before you can do that meaningfully.

> single-thread application ... increment/decrement as atomic operations

There's probably no benefit in this case, unless you're handling interrupts and need consistency between them and your normal code.

Whether your platform *actually* emits the relevant fences/barriers/lock prefixes/CAS/whatever when building a single-threaded app, is a quality of implementation issue. Just look at the assembler output to see.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Reference_counting
Reference counting is a form of garbage collection whereby each object has a count of the number of references to it. Garbage is identified by having a reference count of zero. An object's reference count is incremented when a reference to it is created, and decremented when a reference is destroyed. When the count reaches zero, the object's memory is reclaimed.

Comment: Also, the paper is pretty clear that it puts rc as a type of gc, so your first sentence doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm just now writing a paper observing that tables have both legs and mass. I have legs, and mass. Does that make me a table?

Comment: (Hint - by your logic, I'm an item of furniture. I strenuously dispute this conclusion).

Comment: Reference counting _in the context of garbage collection_ (the article you linked) is that. Reference counting _in general_ is not limited to that, as your comment below Sam's answer admits.

Comment: Your king decrees that you shall be his footstool for the day. :P